# Algorithm for forming pairs in grid of cells

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, combinatorics

Given a grid of an even number of cells where two cells on the edge of the grid are missing, I want to form pairs of adjacent cells in such a way that no cell is left without a partner (not counting the "missing" cells).

Depending on where the two "missing" cells are placed, I believe it's either always possible or always impossible to make such an arrangement. I've drawn two examples here, where the drawing on the left is a successful attempt, and the drawing on the right is an unsuccessful attempt (two cells are left without a partner). Apologies for the shaky camera hand.

[image: Pairs]

The arrows inside the cells indicate which neighbor the cell is partnered with.

I have two questions:

1. How do I know where it is safe to place the "missing" cells, without making it impossible to give every cell a partner?
2. What would an algorithm to create such an arrangement look like, given the conditions I mentioned above, and also given that the cell table can be larger (although always with an even number of cells) and not necessarily square (but rectangular)? Examples could be a 3x4 grid, or a 6x6 grid.

I don't yet know how to know where it is safe to place the "missing" cells, but provided that they are in positions known to be safe, my algorithm is the following:

```
1. For each cell that isn't "missing" or already paired, iterating from top-left to bottom right, horizontally first:
2. Choose a random neighbor to form a pair with: either right or bottom.
3. Check all the cells to see if there are any cells that cannot make a pair, if so:
4. Undo the last pair, go back to 2 and choose the other neighbor.
```

I know absolutely no graph theory or whatever it is that could help me come up with a good solution to this, so I would be very thankful for any help that you can give. Pseudo-code or real code in any not-super-obscure language would be great, as would simple textual explanations.

Comment: you should post your answer here : http://mathoverflow.net/ under the tag co.combinatoric

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm a programmer with very, very little understanding of mathematics, so I doubt I'd be able to understand any answers given - regardless of how accurate they may be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is better known as the [mutilated chessboard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilated_chessboard_problem). The solution, due to Gomory, is first to number the squares of the board from 1 to n^2 so that numbers k and k + 1 are adjacent (and 1 and n^2 are adjacent).

```
 1  2  3  4
16  7  6  5
15  8  9 10
14 13 12 11
```

Now, there is a solution if and only if the two removed numbers are not both even or both odd. If the first removed number is a, then tile (a + 1, a + 2), (a + 3, a + 4), etc., until reaching b. Then tile (b + 1, b + 2), (b + 3, b + 4), etc., until reaching a. (All addition is done modulo n^2, i.e., it "turns the corner" so that n^2 + 1 = 1, etc.)

Here's a 5x6 numbering.

```
 1  2  3  4  5
30  9  8  7  6
29 10 11 12 13
28 17 16 15 14
27 18 19 20 21
26 25 24 23 22
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link! I was writing up an answer involving maximum bipartite matching, but didn't realize that this specific case had already been resolved.

Comment: Wow. Very good answer, with further reading to back it up. Because I'm so mathematically incompetent, it's going to take me a while to digest, but I think I understand the algorithm for tiling. I'm just not sure I understand the numbering system yet, but I'm sure I'll grok it if I give it some time and read up on Gomory's theorem.

Comment: @TommyBrunn It doesn't matter which numbering you pick; the even numbers always will make a checkerboard pattern. The pattern above will generalize if the zigzags are perpendicular to an even-length dimension of the board.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to question 1:

Assume that your board is colored like a checker board with black and white cells. If you pair two cells, you will always take a black and a white cell.

So it is clear that a pairing is impossible if the two missing cells have the same color.

I do not know however, if a pairing is always possible if the missing cells have different color.

Comment: I had made that observation as well, although I had never visualized it in that way, and I have no reasoning for why that is the case. Nevertheless, thank you for your help.